# apply class to row in yajra/datatable if a given model instance has been soft deleted

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

In [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables), I want to determine that current model is soft-deleted or not. if it is deleted , a `success` bootstrap class apply to row containing that model details.

this is my backend code:

```
$courses =
            Course::select(['course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'lesson_count', 'status', 'active', 'teacher','start_date','end_date','reg_start_date','reg_end_date']);

        if ($request->has('showDeleted') && $request->get('showDeleted') == 1) {
            $courses = $courses->withTrashed();
        }

        $datatable = app('datatables')->of($courses)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            //columns come here
            ->setRowClass(function ($course) {
                return ($course->trashed() ? 'danger' : 'sdasd');
            });

        return $datatable->make(true);
```

As you see I used:

```
->setRowClass(function ($course) {
                    return ($course->trashed() ? 'danger' : ' ');
                });
```

to apply desired class But `$course->trashed` return false always for all model instances even those is not trashed.

what is best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was my mistake that I should included `deleted_at` field in columns selection on `select` method:

```
$courses =
Course::select(['course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'lesson_count', 'status', 'active', 'teacher','start_date','end_date','reg_start_date','reg_end_date','deleted_at']);
```